# How do I set the index to the current video file name?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
string t = Options_DB.get_datFileOutputDir();
DirectoryInfo diri = new DirectoryInfo(Options_DB.get_datFileOutputDir());
DirectoryInfo[] finfo = diri.GetDirectories();
_fi = new DirectoryInfo(t + "\\" + finfo[0]).GetFiles("*.bmp");
```

I'm doing: `finfo[0]`

But `finfo` contains in this case two indexes:

- `index[0]` contains this file name: `MVI_4524.MOV`
- `index[1]` contains this file name: `MVI_4526.MOV`

The current video file name is in the variable: `_videoFile`
This variable now contains the file name: `E:\\Stormy Weather\\MVI_4526.MOV`

Now I added to the top of this code : `string currentfn = Path.GetFileName(_videoFile);`
So now `currentfn` contains: `MVI_4526.MOV`

Now the problem is, how do I make that `finfo` instead doing `[0]` to make `currentfn` ?
I mean that the chosen index will be always the current file name.

Answer (score 0):

Found how to do it this is working:

```
string currentfn = Path.GetFileName(_videoFile);
                                string t = Options_DB.get_datFileOutputDir();
                                DirectoryInfo diri = new DirectoryInfo(Options_DB.get_datFileOutputDir());
                                DirectoryInfo[] finfo = diri.GetDirectories();
                                for (int i = 0; i < finfo.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    if (finfo[i].Name == currentfn)
                                    {
                                        _fi = new DirectoryInfo(t + "\\" + finfo[i]).GetFiles("*.bmp");
                                    }
                                }
```